# C# getting last element's attribute values from XML

Tags: c#, xml, xml-parsing, xelement

I have below XML.

```
  <Bd>
  <GEvt ZipCode="xyz" EvtDtm="2020-03-12T02:26:35+01:00"></GEvt>
  <GEvt ZipCode="abc" EvtDtm="2020-03-12T02:32:35+01:00"></GEvt>
  <GEvt ZipCode="def" EvtDtm="2020-03-12T02:34:35+01:00"></GEvt>
  </Bd>
```

I dont need first two. I only need the last one;

```
<GEvt ZipCode="def" EvtDtm="2020-03-12T02:34:35+01:00"></GEvt>
```

Here is my code;

```
  var lineItemDetails = xdoc.Root?.Descendants("Bd");

  foreach (var lineItemDetail in lineItemDetails?.Nodes().OfType<XElement>())
    {
    var ZipCode = lineItemDetail?.Attribute("ZipCode")?.Value;
    var EvtDtm = lineItemDetail?.Attribute("EvtDtm")?.Value;
    Console.WriteLine(ZipCode);
    Console.WriteLine(EvtDtm);
    }
```

It's working fine but it's returning all 3 values from XML. However i only need the last one. I tried to use Last() but it didnt work. Using Last() bringing me last character. I need only this;

```
<GEvt ZipCode="def" EvtDtm="2020-03-12T02:34:35+01:00"></GEvt>
```

How to achieve it? What am i missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check it out. It finds last `<GEvt.../>` XML element based on its position.

> c#

```
void Main()
{
    const string GEVT = "GEvt";
    const string ZIPCODE = "ZipCode";
    const string EVTDTM = "EvtDtm";

    XElement xml = XElement.Parse(@"<Bd>
        <GEvt ZipCode='xyz' EvtDtm='2020-03-12T02:26:35+01:00'></GEvt>
        <GEvt ZipCode='abc' EvtDtm='2020-03-12T02:32:35+01:00'></GEvt>
        <GEvt ZipCode='def' EvtDtm='2020-03-12T02:34:35+01:00'></GEvt>
        </Bd>");

    // get desired XML element
    XElement lastElement = xml.Elements(GEVT).Last();

    // get attributes values
    string Zipcode = lastElement.Attributes(ZIPCODE).FirstOrDefault().Value;
    string EvtDtm = lastElement.Attributes(EVTDTM).FirstOrDefault().Value;
}
```

Comment: But the problem is ZipCode is not equal to def all the time. It's a dynamic value. I need to retrieve the last one regardless of the others.

Comment: I adjusted  the answer.